# Открытие окон в mvvm-light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Как средствами MVVM Light открывать окна в приложении ? 
 Допустим, нужно открыть окно, в которое вводятся данные для добавление нового пользователя ( как пример ) в общий список пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я помню - в данном фрейморке есть `DialogService`. Покопайте в эту сторону - вроде ничего сложного. А так каждый пишет то, во что горазд. Можно отправлять сообщения через `Messanger` и где-то в `code-behind` их ловить и открывать окна, можно свой `IDialogService` написать, можно изобразить окна в виде контролов на главной форме и как-то ими из `MainViewModel` рулить (ну такое). Способов куча.